# Change certificate's recipient name automatically

Tags: print-design, inkscape

I am about to design a certificate for 100 people. It is very time-consuming if I change the certificate's recipient name one by one. Are there any tools that can generate a list of names and paste each name to the certificate? I am currently designing using Inkscape.

Comment: There's a mail merge extension for Inkscape called InkscapeGenerator.  I've never used it, but here's the link. http://wiki.colivre.net/Aurium/InkscapeGenerator If that doesn't work try Scribus - there's a mail merge extension for Scribus too https://github.com/berteh/ScribusGenerator

Comment: I used the Generator extension, and made instructions: https://inkscape.org/en/~Moini/%E2%98%85example-files-for-generator-extension

Answer (score 2):

Since the SVG-format is purely text based, it is easy to solve with most programming languanges.

Here, for example, in bash, assuming that the prepared file "template.svg" contains the name "invitee" to be replaced with the real names from the the file "names.lst":

```
n=0
while read name 
do
  ((n+=1))
  sed "s/invitee/$name/" template.svg > invitation-$n.svg
done < names.lst
```

After saving as numbered invitation-$n.svg, you could export it to png format or convert it to something else in just one line.

The names.lst would just look something like this:

```
Rolling Stones
Carlos Santana
Nina Simone
```

One name per line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Inkscape, but if I have to do that I would save the certificate as an image file format, place it in a **Word** document and create a **mailing list** from an **Excel** file with all the people's names. With this solution you get the 100 certificates not only with different names but also with all the possible different data of each person.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension called [NextGenerator](https://gitlab.com/Moini/nextgenerator). Personally, I tested it and it functioned (Inkscape 1.1.1)! Check example inside repo. Consider writing `%VAR_header%` in your Inkscape project, being `header` the name of the column in your .csv file.